# forgot password to mysql database installed on windows, database is production, is it safe to reset?

Tags: mysql

Someone installed mysql and a web app is using it and we do not know the password.  Not mission critical, it can be down overnight as long as it's up by 8am.

I've seen a few links on resetting passwords - I'd like to try this: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/04/23/reset-the-root-password-of-mysql-server/

The thing is, I am not a mysql admin, just a developer.  Is this safe to try?

Thank you all!

Comment: If you have root access, you should be able to change the user's password without resetting anything.  How do you access mySQL? Through the console, or a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest against using MySQL root accounts for web applications. Any hole in your code could expose your database to a unacceptable risk. If your application is using a root password, please continue reading. Otherwise, just reset the password from your root account (and change the web app configuration to use the new password).

---

Yes, the method described there is safe to be used. Do not forget to remove that SQL file immediately after you've run it and change the passwords inside the applications. Before doing this reset, you might want to deny access to your webapp to avoid information disclosure (e.g. errors about unestablished database connections).

Answer (score 0):

If a web app is using the database, it must have the password stored somewhere. For typical PHP web app, the password is most likely sitting in a config file.

I would explore that first before resetting the password in mysql side. Since, you will have to update web app anyway, it can't hurt to look there first.